# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Working on a command that repeats what the user just said with emojis in between, can't figure it out

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm working on a command called "Catjam" where it repeats what the user just said, with catjam emojis in between. Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def catjam(ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(f"<a:catjam:799725698595946526>{text}<a:catjam:799725698595946526>")
```

This is what the command looks like in action:[image]

That is fine, but I want it to look like this:[image]

Not sure how to accomplish that, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```py
>>> message = "whatever"
>>> new_message = ""
>>> 
>>> for char in message:
...    new_message += f"✅{char}"
... 
>>> 
>>> new_message += "✅"
>>> new_message
'✅w✅h✅a✅t✅e✅v✅e✅r'
```

Comment: I tried this out, gives me an error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_messsage' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I think the error pretty much speaks for itself, you need to first define the `new_message` variable (as an empty string), like so `new_message = ""` and then add to it in the for loop. My code works perfectly fine, you copied something wrong

Comment: Hmm I think I copied it right, though I could be wrong. Here's what I have (with some adjustments to fit my code): `@client.command()
async def catjam(ctx, *, text):
    message = f"{text}"
    new_message = ""
    for char in message:
      new_messsage += f"<a:catjam:799725698595946526>{char}"
    new_message += "<a:catjam:799725698595946526>"
    await ctx.send(new_message)`

Comment: Haha there's a typo! in the for loop you defined `new_messsage` with 3 `s`'s instead of 2